# qtoxygen style without shadow frame

Tags: css, qt

I'm using qtoxygen style. Do someone know how to disable shadow frame on QPlainTextEdit? If I customise css with { border: none } the shadow would still be painting.(((

Answer (score 0):

Solved via css
QAbstractScrollArea { qproperty-frameShape: NoFrame; }